# Magic: The Gathering - Why is it possible to activate some cards abilities from graveyard and some others not?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are some cards, that have activated abilities, that a player can activate when the card is in the graveyard. For example, the ability of Stitchwing Skaab to return it from the graveyard to the battlefield.

[image: Stitchwing Skaab]

However, most of the other card abilities, a player can't activate from the graveyard. For example, Drogskol Cavalry's ability to put a spirit token to the battlefield can not be activated when it's in the graveyard.

[image: Drogskol Cavalry]

So my question is, which rule of the game allowing a player to activate some abilities from the graveyard?

Comment: The addition "from your graveyard". Have a look at "flashback" or "escape" mechanics.

Comment: @Erik Sure, but where's this specified in the CR?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Comprehensive Rule 113.6](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr113/):

> 113.6. Abilities of an instant or sorcery spell usually function only while that object is on the stack. Abilities of all other objects usually function only while that object is on the battlefield. The exceptions are as follows:
>
> [ ... ]
>
> 113.6k An ability whose cost or effect specifies that it moves the object it’s on out of a particular zone functions only in that zone, unless its trigger condition or a previous part of its cost or effect specifies that the object is put into that zone or, if the object is an Aura, that the object it enchants leaves the battlefield. The same is true if the effect of that ability creates a delayed triggered ability whose effect moves the object out of a particular zone
>
> *Example: Reassembling Skeleton says “{1}{B}: Return Reassembling Skeleton from your graveyard to the battlefield tapped.” A player may activate this ability only if Reassembling Skeleton is in their graveyard.*

Comment: In short, ability activation is possible wherever it needs to be possible in order for the ability to ever be functional on its own.

Comment: @Douglas Except characteristic-defining abilities. They function everywhere, even outside a game.

Comment: @Douglas I don't think so, take the Drogskol Cavalry example from the question. That ability is perfectly possible to function on its own; compare with (say) Bridge from Below.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Exactly. Drogskol's ability is possible to function on its own. Therefore, it acting in the graveyard is not need for it "to be possible in order for the ability to ever be functional on its own." If it's impossible for an ability to ever function except for in the graveyard, then it functions in the graveyard.

Comment: @ikegami Are there activated characteristic defining abilities?

Comment: @corsiKa, I didn't notice Douglas limited the short version to activated abilities. (The answer wasn't limited to activated abilities.) With that in mind, one can read my comment as saying the following: This is not just the case for activated abilities. This applies to all abilities, except that characteristic-defining abilities function everywhere.

Comment: @Philip Kendall, Douglas was imprecise. They were describing where the ability works if the ability wouldn't ever function on the stack (instants and sorceries) or battlefield (others). Ex1) Drogskol Cavalry isn't an instant of sorc or instant, so its abilities only work on the battlefield by default. Since they can work on the battlefield, they only work on the battlefield. Ex2) Bridge from Below's abilities couldn't possibly work from the battlefield, so they only work from the graveyard.

Comment: @ikegami Side note, there's a reason I specified "on its own" in there. For example, if Reassembling Skeleton's ability could be activated on the battlefield, and it got an exception for tracking across zone transitions, you could activate it, sacrifice it for something else while the ability's on the stack, and get it back, making the ability technically functional from the battlefield. That requires interactions outside the ability, however, so it doesn't count.

Comment: @PhilipKendall That's a supporting example to my comment, not a counterexample. Drogskol can function on the battlefield, so it only works there. Bridge can't possibly work anywhere *except* the graveyard, so it works in the graveyard.

Comment: @Douglas, What you said  was wrong. Drogskol Cavalry's ability does not need to be on the battlefield to ever be functional on its own, yet it only works on the battlefield. My previous comment explained what you left out.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I know. I was pointing out something extra, not arguing against you. Sorry I didn't make that clear enough.

Comment: @Douglas isn't it not necessarily true that activating the reassembling skeleton on the battlefield would return it from the graveyard because the one that goes to the graveyard would be a different object from the one that died? I know that example was assuming we could activate it on the battlefield so the rules may not cover such a hypothetical situation but was curious if I was interpreting that correctly. I understand what you're getting at though for the sake of making an example.

Comment: @MaxYoung That's what the "and it got an exception for tracking across zone transitions" clause is for.